# Can I merge these two if-statements?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (a || b)
{
    X();
}

if (a)
{
    Y();
}
```

Can I somehow merge these two if-statements?

Comment: Do bear in mind there is value in leaving the code readable.

Comment: I thought I just made it readable.

Comment: What you have is readable and easy to parse quickly. On a technical level I'd be interested to see what code people come up with, but I'd likely still just stick with this or migrate the check into a named method or something.

Comment: This also depends much on the context. If this is the only content of a method you could return if `!a`, then call X and have another if for Y. Depending on the context any of the solutions might be more or less readable I think.

Comment: Alternative answer would be like this:

    if (a){
      X();
      Y();
    } else if (b) {
      X();
    } it is quite readable and clear, I think.

Comment: Is there any chance of `X()` modifying the value of `a`?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy No, good point though.

Comment: @Ian That's true for this example. For my code X() and Y() are two and four lines of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be better, because if first loop exits because a and b are false, then there is no need to check the second loop-

```
if(a||b)
{
    X();
    if(a)
    {
       Y();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your Y() method always returns true you can write:

```
if(a || Y() || b) X();
```

But you need take in account that this code will be read by another person, so it should be easy readable and explain its meaning for the other person. So the best solution depends on meaning of a, b, X and Y. And all of the following will be correct with different semantic meanings:

```
if(a || b)
{
    X();
    if(a) Y();
}
```

or

```
if(a)
{
    X();
    Y();
}
else if(b)
{
    Y();
}
```

Comment: If `Y() ` returns anything that can be cast to boolean then you could use `(Y() || true)` as long as that's not optimised away. You do lose some readability like this, so it's not really a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, maybe you could pass the value onto the X method and if it's A it will then call Y only giving you one if statement. This honestly is a far more clear way to handle it